# Help using Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

I want to use Gram-Schmidt to turn the vectors $v_{1}=(1,\sqrt{2},1,0)$, $v_{2} = (\sqrt{2},1,0,1)$, $v_{3}= (\frac{-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}i}{2},-i,\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}i}{2},1)$ and $v_{4} = (\frac{-(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}i)}{2},i,\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}i}{2},1)$ into an orthonormal system.

*My work:* The first vector, let us call it $\hat{v}_{1}$, is simply $\hat{v}_{1} = \frac{v_{1}}{||v_{1}||} = \frac{1}{2}v_{1} = \frac{1}{2}(1,\sqrt{2},1,0)$. Now, using $\langle v_{2},\hat{v}_{1}\rangle = \sqrt{2}$, and $||v_{2}||=2$, I got:
$$\hat{v}_{2} = \frac{1}{||v_{2}||}(v_{2} -\langle v_{2},\hat{v}_{1}\rangle \hat{v}_{1}) = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0,-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},1)$$

Now, using $\langle v_{3}, \hat{v}_{1}\rangle = \langle v_{3},\hat{v}_{2}\rangle = 0$, and $||v_{3}|| = 2$, I got $\hat{v}_{3} = \frac{1}{||v_{3}||}v_{3} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}i}{2},-i,\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}i}{2},1)$.

Finally, using $\langle v_{4},\hat{v}_{1}\rangle = \langle v_{4},\hat{v}_{2}\rangle = \langle v_{4},\hat{v}_{3}\rangle = 0$ and $||v_{4}|| = 2$, I got $\hat{v}_{4} = \frac{1}{||v_{4}||}v_{4} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{-(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}i)}{2},i,\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}i}{2},1)$.

The point is: if I define a matrix $U$ whose columns are, respectively, the vectors $\hat{v}_{1}$, $\hat{v}_{2}$, $\hat{v}_{3}$ and $\hat{v}_{4}$, that is:
$$U = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \frac{-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}i}{2} & \frac{-(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}i)}{2}\\
\sqrt{2} & -1 & -i & i \\
1 & -\sqrt{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}i}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}i}{2} \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and evaluate the product $UU^{*}$ it is not the identity map. Can someone help me spot the mistake? Thanks!

Comment: You need to us the normalized vectors in the matrix.

Comment: @CyclotomicField ops,I forgot the $1/2$ factor. However, this changes nothing actually.

Comment: You can only get the identity matrix if the dot product of the vector with itself is one. This only happens when the length of the vector is one. Using an unnormalized vector will always ensure $UU^*$ is not the identity map.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I inserted the normalizing factor $1/2$. But the point is that the product $UU^{*}$ gives an uggly matrix, not even close to the identity.

Comment: Then the columns are not orthogonal. Note that $v_1 \cdot v_2 = -\sqrt{2} \neq 0$.

Comment: You are right. I corrected the $\hat{v}_{2}$ term. However, there is another mistake since $UU^{*}$ is still not the identity matrix.

Comment: You'll have to check every column to ensure they're all mutually orthogonal. If the diagonal is not $1$ then the vector is not normalized and if they off-diagonal are not zero then two vectors are not orthogonal.

Comment: @Ramanujan thanks. Going to edit it However, the result is correct.

Comment: Based on [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=orthogonalize+%28%281%2C+Sqrt%282%29%2C+1%2C+0%29%2C+%28Sqrt%282%29%2C+1%2C+0%2C+1%29%2C++%28%5Cfrac%7B-%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B2%7Di%7D%7B2%7D%2C-i%2C%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B2%7Di%7D%7B2%7D%2C1%29%2C+%28%5Cfrac%7B-%28%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B2%7Di%29%7D%7B2%7D%2Ci%2C%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D-%5Csqrt%7B2%7Di%7D%7B2%7D%2C1%29%29) I think that your $\hat{v}_2$ is incorrect.

Comment: I got it guys! The problem is that I was defining $\hat{v}_{i}$ normalizing by $||v_{i}||$ but the formula states that the normalization should be made after that.